# Is it possible to automatically select command option while running extension command in task?

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks, plantuml

I’m using «PlantUML» extension, and I want to export diagram automatically on file save. For this purpose I found «Trigger Task on Save» extension and tried write task that will execute command «command:plantuml.exportCurrent» on save of any .puml file.

settings.json (for «Trigger Task on Save» extension)

```
{
    "triggerTaskOnSave.on": true,
    "triggerTaskOnSave.restart": true,
    "triggerTaskOnSave.tasks": {
        "Export current diagram to SVG": [
            "*.puml"
        ]
    },
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Export current diagram to SVG",
            "command": "${command:plantuml.exportCurrent}",
        }
    ],
}
```

This export command requires from user to select file format [(file format select options)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSbbD.jpg). I need to export diagram in svg format. Is it possible to automatically select «svg» option in task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible if you set (in the PlantUML extension) your export format to SVG (so it won't ask you the format when you export):

[image]

Comment: I can’t believe I missed that option, that solves the issue. Thank you. But still maybe in future in some other extension I will need to do as I described above, is it possible?

Comment: @Artemio as a general problem in VSCode, I am not sure. There are probably ways with GUI scripting tools in Windows or other OS.